# How to get all columns with the same column name in R at once?

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
> test <- cbind(test=c(1, 2, 3), test=c(1, 2, 3))
> test
     test test
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    3    3
```

Now from such data frame I want to fetch all the columns named "test" to a new data frame:

```
> new_df <- test[, "test"]
```

However this last attempt to do so only fetches the first column called "test" in test data frame:

```
> new_df
[1] 1 2 3
```

How can I get all of the columns called "test" in this example and put them into a new data frame in a single command? In my real data I have many columns with repeated colnames and I don't know the index of the columns so I can`t get them by number.

Comment: Do you want something like this? `test[,grepl("test", colnames(test)) ]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not advisable to have same column names for practical reasons.  But, we can do a comparison (`==`) to get a logical vector and use that to extract the  columns

```
i1 <- colnames(test) == "test"
new_df <- test[, i1, drop = FALSE]
```

---

Note that `data.frame` doesn't allow  duplicate column names and would change it to unique by appending `.1` `.2` etc at the end with `make.unique`.  With `matrix` (the  OP's dataset), allows to have duplicate column names or row names (not recommended though)

---

Also, if there are multiple column names that are repeated and want to select them as separate datasets, use `split`

```
lst1 <- lapply(split(seq_len(ncol(test)), colnames(test)), function(i)
            test[, i, drop = FALSE])
```

Or loop through the `unique` column names and do a `==` by looping through it with `lapply`

```
lst2 <- lapply(unique(colnames(test)), function(nm) 
             test[, colnames(test) == nm, drop = FALSE])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the explanation I needed